# AWS API Gateway with VPC Load Balancer redirects to incorrect path (prefix not omitted)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-application-load-balancer

I want to use API Gateway to route between multiple microservices. E.g: `domain.com/app1`, `domain.com/app2` etc.

- Each service has an **internal** Application Load Balancer (ALB).
- API Gateway has a VPC Link configured correctly.

The problem is that routes such as `domain.com/app1/hello` are redirected to `internal.app1/app1/hello` instead of `internal.app1/hello`.

- Notice that the prefix `app1` is not removed.

It can be solved when I use HTTP redirection in API Gateway, but that requires an *external* load balancer which I want to avoid. I didn't see an option to use *path variables* with private ALB integration.

Please advise. Thank you in advance.

Comment: REST API or HTTP?

Comment: @AndrewGillis HTTP

Comment: I'm guessing you are using the console? Have you tried specifying parameter mapping through IaC or CLI?

Comment: @AndrewGillis Yes, I'm using the AWS Management Console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved.

The solution is to use a REST API Gateway (instead of HTTP Gateway) integrated with a **Network Load Balancer** (NLB) via a VPC Link.

The AWS **REST API** in AWS API Gateway allows using *path variables* with private integration (in this case, the NLB).

Summary of the solution:

- API Gateway REST API
- Private Network Load Balancer
- REST API VPC Link (to the NLB)
- Use a *proxy resource* with *private integration* in the routes configuration